# Can I continue a machine learning process after shutdown?

Tags: deep-learning, jupyter

I use Mask RCNN for object detection and instance segmentation.
I am new to neural networks, this is my first project.

I use jupyter notebook. Can I continue learning after shutdown? 
[image]

I would like start learning from 6 epoch. How can I do it? 
One epoch ~ 1h. I don't want to waste time, and continue this process. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In order to continue the learning process, you will need to [use checkpoints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxtBIwfy0kM).

```
# source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36356004/continue-training-from-a-specific-epoch
weight_save_callback = ModelCheckpoint('/path/to/weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=False, mode='auto')
model.fit(X_train,y_train,batch_size=batch_size,nb_epoch=nb_epoch,callbacks=[weight_save_callback])

# load model
model = Sequential()
model.add(...)
model.load('path/to/weights.hf5')

# use model.fit to continue training.
```